# What is the cause of JVM exit code 1073807364?

Tags: java, windows-xp, jvm, sun, exit-code

I've built a RCP-based application, and one of my users running on Windows XP, Sun JVM 1.6.0_12 had a full application crash.  After the app was running for two days (and this is not a new version or anything), he got the nice gray JVM force exit box, with exit code=1073807364.

He was away from the machine at the time, and the only thing I can find near that time in the application logs was some communication with the database (SQL Server by way of Hibernate).  There's no hs_ files or anything similar as far as I can tell.  Web searching found a bunch of crash reports with that exit code in a variety of applications, but I didn't see any fundamental explanation of what causes it.

Can anyone tell me what causes it?  Is there additional information likely to have been dumped that could prove useful?

Comment: (FWIW, according to google "1073807364 in base 16" is 0x40010004.)

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell, this error code (0x40010004) arises in all sorts of situations, with (as you noted) no obvious common thread.

However [this page](http://www.computing.net/answers/windows-xp/notification-of-a-failed-job/99006.html) says "0x40010004" means "the task is running"!  So, I would *surmise* that the correct way to interpret it is as saying "this tasked has exited in a way that prevented it setting a proper exit code".

I don't know if this will help, but I would try looking in the Windows Event logs to see if the problem is being reported there.

Comment: Well, there's nothing in the Windows app or system event logs.  Is it possible this is a coincidental match of error codes between Windows and Sun's JVM?  Assuming that a 'Windows task' is some kind of cron job, this app is definitely not starting one that I know of.  Any idea of how to find out if 'Windows task' are involved here?