# Java was started but returned exit code=1073807364

Tags: eclipse, java, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I am using STS, jdk 1.6. It was working fine until now. I am getting this STS pop-up when I start it.

```
   Java was started but returned exit code=1073807364
   C:/jdk1.6.0_18/bin/javaw.exe
   -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
   ...
   ... /15 more lines of stack on the pop-up window.
```

Any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174080/what-is-the-cause-of-jvm-exit-code-1073807364 - though I just realized that question wasn't really answered. nvm

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174080/what-is-the-cause-of-jvm-exit-code-1073807364

Comment: you beat me to it... the system won't let me delete my comment though

Comment: I actually just edited mine - it seems that question wasn't really answered. There are a few google results for it. I think we need more information. It seems like this is a sort of cross-threading issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this; Looks like there is no one problem, that error code can come from a variety of events.

From what I can tell, this error code (0x40010004) arises in all sorts of situations, with (as you noted) no obvious common thread.

However this page says "0x40010004" means "the task is running"! So, I would surmise that the correct way to interpret it is as saying "this tasked has exited in a way that prevented it setting a proper exit code".

I don't know if this will help, but I would try looking in the Windows Event logs to see if the problem is being reported there.

found here: [What is the cause of JVM exit code 1073807364?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174080/what-is-the-cause-of-jvm-exit-code-1073807364)

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, that error (described as "task is running") occurs when there is a thread in blocking mode, and the thread cannot be terminated by being interrupted (per the rules) so it lingers, causing the program to hang, and requiring a kill shot. I have experienced that error as recently as today (Sept 5, 2012), and that was the cause (because I did it deliberately).

There may be other causes, but that is one distinct possibility.

Answer (score 1):

All I can suggest is updating your [JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) to the latest release ([1.6.0_23](https://cds.sun.com/is-bin/INTERSHOP.enfinity/WFS/CDS-CDS_Developer-Site/en_US/-/USD/ViewProductDetail-Start?ProductRef=jdk-6u23-oth-JPR@CDS-CDS_Developer)) and [STS](http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts) to the latest version (2.5.2) and seeing if the problem still persists.

Comment: Speaking of which, why is it that the Java JRE has an autoupdater, but the JDK doesn't?  So stupid...